kamailio issue with lock function
$var(hjoin) = 0;
lock("$rU");
$var(hjoin) = $sht(vtp=>join::$tU);
$var(hstored) = $sht(vtp=>stored::$tU);
$sht(vtp=>join::$tU) = $null;

Received Error Message:
Error -> Sep 17 04:50:02 kamailio: 
 ERROR: [core/cfg.y:3870]: yyparse(): cfg. parser: 
 failed to find command lock (params 1) Sep 17 04:50:02 kamailio: 
 CRITICAL: [core/cfg.y:4011]: yyerror_at(): 
  parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 715, column 12: 
    unknown command, missing loadmodule?#012

As far as I know, the lock function belongs to the tm.so module. I've already loaded that, so still I don't understand why I am facing this error.

lock(...) function is exported by the cfgutils module, not tm, be sure this one is loaded:

https://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/stable/modules/cfgutils.html#cfgutils.f.lock

